# XNA Disable Auto Fit to Screen

Tags: c#, .net, xna-4.0

I'm using the XNA 4.0 framework to create a business intelligence screen that will be projected in a control room.  The screen itself is designed to fit on two 1920 * 1080 projectors in series.

Currently I'm defining the resolution of the screen as follows:

```
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 3840;
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 1080;
```

However if I run the solution, XNA automatically 'squashes' the 2D graphics so that the entire screen fits on my primary 1920 * 1080 screen.  How do you disable this 're-sizing' functionality in XNA?  What I want to achieve is one big screen that I can show across two 1920 * 1080 monitors.  Not a squashed screen that fits on one monitor.

Note that my XNA knowledge is very limited.  I'm using SpriteFonts and Texture2D to create the graphic objects

Comment: The only way I've found to do it is to get a device that makes it look like a single 3840x1080 screen. I think its because DirectX can't share a single device context across two monitors.

Comment: Ron, thanks for the comment.  What do you mean by "get a device that makes it look like a single 3840x1080" screen?  Please define 'device'.

Comment: I've used the triple head version of this: http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/

Comment: Great stuff, I think that is exactly what I need.  Thanks a million

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should work **if** you are setting those values on the Game class constructor and have configured the screens to expand content between themselves.

Another, not really recommended, way to do it is to apply the changes on either the `Initialize` or `LoadContent` method.

In order to do this, just add the following line after setting the dimensions:

```
this.graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

So your whole thing would look like this:

```
protected virtual void Initialize()
{
    this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1024;
    this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
    this.graphics.ApplyChanges();
}
```

If you do not want to use the ApplyChanges method, you can set the values on the class constructor **without** calling this method.

Also, be sure to check that the `graphics.IsFullScreen` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphicsdevicemanager.isfullscreen.aspx) is not set to true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I see what you mean.  If I enable extended display in windows, XNA does not compress the screen, and I can manually drag the XNA screen to fit both physical screen.  However if I run in fullscreen mode, the first half of the uncompressed screen is displayed on my primary screen.  It does not fill both screens.

The reason why I want it to work in fullscreen mode, is because the windows frame around the XNA screen is ugly and completely destroys the look and feel of the product.  It seems like Ron Beyer's solution will help with this issue

Comment: @user1035217 If your only issue now is the frame of the XNA window, you can always [hide it](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/14839/14839.aspx) by code and leave only your game content on display!

Comment: That worked!  Thanks.  I had to add the following code to position the screen across both physical screens:

form.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-1920, 0);

Comment: I'm not sure, but that probably is because you had the right side screen configured as the primary monitor, but don't quote me on that, it's just a guess! :)